# Dynamic stored procedure - How do I plug in a % in a like clause if building dynamically like this?

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic

I need help with this proc.  This is a snippet.

Essentially, based on input params I need to dynamically define the sql - select values and where conditions to include.

I'm just including keyID here but plan to have a bunch of different parameters which redefines(adds) to the where clause.

**Problem- How do I plug in a % at the end of the input param?**

Justification for WHY I'm asking this question:

This is an intranet app so I'm not concerned about malicious SQL injection.

I have no concern for scalability.

The reason I'm doing it this way is I need to know how to do a dynamic sql in a procedure.

In my particular case, I will run two separate queries based on other information supplied to me.

So my choice is to make a ton of IF ELSE conditions(probably 16 different queries) or to make a more simplier dynamic query based on input parameters.

Please advise.

```
create or replace
PACKAGE BODY PK_SEARCH AS
 PROCEDURE DELETEME_SP_SEARCH(keyID IN varchar2, keyID2 IN varchar2,
       c_dbuser OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)  
IS
   query_str VARCHAR2(10000);

BEGIN

  query_str := 'select * '
  || 'from customer '
  || 'where key like :a ';  --PROBLEM

   IF keyID2 IS NOT NULL THEN
    query_str := query_str || 'and key2 like :b ';
   END IF;   

    OPEN c_dbuser FOR
         query_str USING keyID, keyID2;
END;


END PK_SEARCH
```

Comment: instead of plugging in the % in the procedure, have you tried passing in the % as part of the parameter?  (exec deleteme_sp_search('MY_KEY%', 'ANOTHER_KEY%')

Answer (score 0):

First, why do you need to add the wild card character in your query?  Why not add it to your bind variable?  Something like

```
 OPEN c_dbuser 
  FOR query_str
USING keyID || '%', keyID2 || '%';
```

Of course, you can't do that with the code snippet you've posted.  If `keyID2` is `NULL`, there will only be one bind variable in the SQL statement that you are assembling so you'd need to pass only one variable in the `USING` section of your `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement.  I don't know if you just inadvertently left out the `ELSE` clause that would add an alternate predicate if `keyID2 IS NULL` so that you can use a variable number of `USING` parameters or if you really need to be using `dbms_sql`.